# Python substring between spaces at user defined index

Tags: python

I am new to Python, have been watching videos on Youtube and trying to learn.

I am trying to `substring` a text between two spaces from a line. Let me explain, what exactly I am trying.

1) I have a text like mentioned below:

`CREATE TABLE DATABASENAME.TABLENAME AS SELECT ....`

2) Now from the above text I want to retrieve only `DATABASENAME.TABLENAME`

3) So I want to extract text between second space and third space, ie. I want to extract text between index numbered 13 and 35, but on basis on spaces.

Can anyone help? Please.

Comment: `yourstring.split()[2]` ?

Comment: check out [Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) Another good site to test your expression is [here](https://regex101.com/) . It is hard in the beginning but once you get it they are very useful.

Comment: Please post your attempt

Comment: str.split() splits on spaces

Comment: mystring  = "CREATE TABLE DABASENAME.TABLENAME AS SELECT ..."
mylist = mystring.split(" ")
print(mylist)
print(mylist[2])

This is what I have till now.

Answer (score 1):

```
string='CREATE TABLE DATABASENAME.TABLENAME AS SELECT'
extract=string.split(' ')[2]
```

Comment: whitespace is by default, so split() is enuff

Comment: it's not default.

Comment: @CSMaverick yes it is - [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: Of course you can use it in Python2 but not in 3 you will end up with `ValueError: empty separator`

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string into list of words based on spaces then get the elements by index in this case it's 2.

```
s = 'CREATE TABLE DATABASENAME.TABLENAME AS SELECT'
print(s.split(' ')) #['CREATE', 'TABLE', 'DATABASENAME.TABLENAME', 'AS', 'SELECT']
print(s.split(' ')[2]) #DATABASENAME.TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split a python string by space with `string.split()`. This  will break up your text into 'words', then you can simply access the 3rd word like this:

```
word_3 = string.split()[2]
```

For more complex patterns, you can use regex, which is a powerful string pattern finding tool.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: @AtulG insteead of saying "thank you" say thank you by up voting and marking an answer as accepted ;-)

Comment: @MaxS He doesn't have enough rep to upvote unless you +1 his question

Comment: @DeltaMarine101 now he does ;-D

Comment: @MaxS Upvote done!!!

Like I already posted, I had solution to this but want to know if there was any other way of doing this. Anyway, thanks for letting me know about "Upvote".

Comment: @DeltaMarine101 Thank you for assisting. I am new to Stackoverflow as well and this was my first question.

Comment: No problem! Read through the answers you got and accept the best one (click the tick ✓). Hopefully you feel comfortable asking questions here in the future if you ever need help again:)